# Grouping/clustering algorithms with uncertain distance metrics

Tags: algorithm, statistics, grouping, cluster-analysis

I need some guidance on how to improve a clustering algorithm. The answer may be trivial, or impossible. I googled a lot, but I either don't understand the analogy between my problem and known clustering algorithms, or such an anlogy is not there. I'm not a computer scientists, and I may misunderstand a lot of the jargon too.

**The problem**

I am given a set of `N` elements, and I need to group these elements in `K` groups, with `K` unknown. The grouping is based on a call to a function `measure(group)`, that returns a measure of how close together the elements in the group are. `group` stands for a collection of at least two elements. Further complicating factors are that the result of `measure` is very uncertain when `group` only has two elements, and that a call to this function is expensive.

**My solution**

Take an empty list of assigned elements, `A`.

Since the result of `measure` is not precise for two elements, to start "seeding" a group, I take the first element `x0`, append it to `A` and then iterate over all other elements, `xi`. I call `measure` with the combinations of two points `(x0, xi)` until I get a `measure` that is so small that I can be confident about it. If this never happens, the `x0` is a one-element group and I move on. If I get a good measure, `xi` is added to the group and to the list of assigned elements `A`. Once this seed is found, I then restart iterating over all elements, excluding the elements already in `A` (I may have missed some elements in the group, because `measure` is uncertain for two elements). For each new candidate element `x`, I call `measure` with the `group` collected until now, and `x` appended to it. If `x` does not increase "a lot" the `measure` of `group`, it is added to `group` and to `A`. I have a way to define precisely "a lot", but that's a detail of the specific problem I have.

When I finish iterating over all elements, I restart for a new group from the first element not already in `A`, always skipping the elements in `A`, until I grouped all elements.

**What's wrong with it?**

The solution is remarkably robust for the specific problem I am working with. However, it is `n^2`in the worst case (iteration over all combinations of the elements in groups of 2). This never happens in practice and my `n` seldom goes beyond a few hundred, but in some pathological cases the worst-case is approached. Since the call to `measure` is so expensive, solving the problem with less iterations would be highly beneficial. And, I guess, an `n^2`solution is never ideal...

Comment: The complexity likely is even O(n³) because you repeat the n² process. This is a slight variation of HAC. If the number of elements is never going to pass, say, 10000, then don't even think about asymptotic complexity. Constant factors will dominate. If you want it to be faster, rewrite it in C (assuming it is *slow* python or R right now).

Comment: I will look at hierarchical clustering (that's HAC, right?), thanks a lot. It's already in C++! It's not really a bottleneck (yet), but let's say that, as a fun project, I'd like to make it faster. I wrote it from scratch (I'm totally new to these kind of things) so I now feel some kind of sentimental attachment to it...

Comment: If you want to learn some interesting approaches for this, have a look at the nnchain approach (nearest neighbor chain) for HAC, which may be applicable here, too.

Comment: I must admit that what I really don't get, at least until now, is the link between the "distance" of HAC methods and my measure function.

Comment: Smallest distance = best merge.